# How to SELECT for the following?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, nested-sets

I have a table DOCUMENTS and a table FOLDERS

```
FOLDERS
ID
lft
rgt

DOCUMENTS
ID
folderID -> FOLDERS(ID)
title
```

So, what we have here is an arbitrarily deep tree of folders (nested-sets).  Each folder can contain an arbitrary number of documents.

What is the most efficient way to SELECT all of the documents that are beneathe a certain folder?  That is, I want to SELECT not only the documents that are in a folder, but the documents that are in that folder's subfolders.

Edit:  Sample data to make things more clear:

```
FOLDERS
ID     LFT     RGT
1      1       10      
2      2       5
3      3       4
4      6       7
5      8       9
```

This represents a folder structure like so...

```
       1
    2  4  5
 3
```

Where 2, 4, 5 are children of 1, and 3 is a child of 2

Now...

Let's say DOCUMENTS has the following data...

```
DOCUMENTS
ID     FolderID    Title
1      5           Doc 1
2      3           Doc 2
3      2           Doc 3
```

Given the ID of a folder, I want to SELECT all of the documents in that folder, and all of the documents in that folder's subfolders.  So for example given a folderID of 2, the SELECT would return documents 2 and 3

Thanks (in advance) for your help

Comment: How about some sample data and desired results for that data? Your question as stated is entirely too vague.

Comment: @mellamokb, it's Modified Preorder Tree Traversal: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll want to get the `lft` and `rgt` values from the folders table:

```
select lft, rgt from folders where id = 2;
```

...then use those to identify documents that exist within that node or its children:

```
select d.* from documents d left join folders f on f.id = d.folderID where f.lft >= 2 and f.rgt <= 5;
```

You can call these two queries separately in your code, you could combine them with subqueries, or you could write a stored procedure that combines them.

Comment: then do the same procedure for lft and rgt folders, and it's lft/rgt folders, and it's lft/rgt folders, and it's lft/rgt folders?

Comment: Ah, beautiful.  Simple and elegant.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nicklamort - In a nested set the lft and rgt values of subfolders always fall between the lft and rgt values of a parent folder.

Comment: Oh, I see. That would make it easier ;p